# perl regex help matching varying number values

Tags: regex

Looking for some help with this perl regex.

I need to extract (3) items from this filename: **abc101.name.aue-abc_p002.20110124.csv**

abc`101`.name.`aue`-abc_p`002`.20110124.csv

where item (3) in this example 002, can also be a max of 4 digits, 0002

Here's my non working regex:

```
while (my $line=<>) {
  chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ m/abc(d{3}).name.(w{3})_p([0-9]).[0-9].csv/) {
      print $1;
      print $2;
      print $3;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (my $line=<>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /^abc(\d{3})\.name\.(\w{3})-abc_p(\d{1,4})\.\d+.csv$/) {
    print $1;
    print $2;
    print $3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean the last dot is literal?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few plus signs (or { } quantifiers) and escaping the dots:
`abc(d{3})\.name\.(w{3})_p([0-9]{3,4})\.[0-9]+\.csv/`

Answer (score 0):

Untested: `/^abc(\d{3})\.name\.([a-z]{3})-abc_p(\d{1,4})\.\d+\.csv$/`